# ¿Como insertar una ecuación multilínea en una tabla de latex?

Tags: latex

mi pregunta es cómo introducir una ecuación multilínea (o varias ecuaciones en distintas líneas) en una casilla de una tabla de latex.
La tabla la tengo hecha de la siguiente forma:

```
\begin{table}[h]
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
       Casilla 1 & Casilla 2 & Casilla 3 \\ \hline
       Casilla 4 & Casilla 5 & Casilla 6 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{table}
```

He probado con "multiline", "gather", "align" y me da error. Sin embargo, fuera de la tabla no me da error alguno.
Espero que me ayuden con mi problema.
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para introducir material multi-linea en una casilla de una tabla (ya sea un entorno matemático multi-ecuación o simplemente un párrafo) la columna a que pertenece esa celda ha de ser tipo `p` y debes especificar su ancho.

Esto puedes hacerlo en el parámetro que recibe `tabular`, por ejemplo `\begin{tabular}{|c|p{5cm}|c}`, en cuyo caso todas las celdas de esa columna son de ese ancho y de tipo "párrafo", o bien en una celda concreta usando `\multicolumn` para esa celda.

Un ejemplo para el segundo enfoque:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
       \hline
       Casilla 1 & \multicolumn{1}{|p{5cm}|}{
         \begin{gather*}
            y = x^2 \\
            z = \log(y)\\
            w = 3z + 2x
         \end{gather*}
       }
       & Casilla 3 \\ \hline
       Casilla 4 & Casilla 5 & Casilla 6 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Produce:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Una respuesta alternativa a la aceptada, incluso sin `amsmath` (*plain* LaTeX):

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  Casilla 1 & %
  \centering
  \ensuremath{%
  \begin{array}{c}
    x+y = 1\\
    x+2y = 2\\
    x+y+z = 3
  \end{array}
  } & Casilla 3\\ \hline
  Casilla 4 & Casilla 5 & Casilla 6\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Agregue esto al header para mejorar los márgenes:

```latex
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1em}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
```

[image: screenshot of output]

Lo siento pero solo hablo italiano y utilicé el traductor de Google :)